# Optimizing a query that extracts ids then messages based on that id

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and wanted to know if this function can be optimized.
Essentially what I would like to do is get a list of all unique ids that happened in the last 3 days.
Then extract the last 6 records of each of those ids. The following works for me but I wanted to know if this can be optimized for 1000s of records.

My structure looks like this

```
public class ModelMessage
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ModelMessageId { get; set; }
    public string TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

and this is what I am doing

```
    private List<ModelMessage> Results()
    {
        //last 3 days
        int days = days * -1;
        List<ModelMessage> collection = new List<ModelMessage>();
        DateTime currenteDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(days);
        DbContext dbcontext = new DbContext(ConString);
        
        //Get all the unique ids that were added 3 days ago
        List<string> listIds = dbcontext.Messages.Where(x => (x.DateAdded > currenteDate)).Select(x => x.TaskId).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (string id in listIds)
        {
            //Get the last 6 records of each of those ids
            collection.AddRange(dbcontext.Messages.Where(x => (x.TaskId == id)).OrderBy(order => order.DateAdded).TakeLast(6));
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas if this method can be optimized (Both C# and Entity related) for speed and performance.

Comment: The version is 6.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compose query logic in EF, try not to run multiple queries.  Each time you run `foreach`, `ToList()`, `First()`, etc you *run* the query.

Instead compose queries (IQueryable) together and run the query at the end.  Here that looks something like this:

```
var taskIds = (from m in db.ModelMessages
               where m.DateAdded >= DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-3)
               select m.TaskId).Distinct();

var q = from t in taskIds
        from m in db.ModelMessages
                    .Where(m => m.TaskId == t)
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.DateAdded)
                    .Take(6)
        select m;

var results = q.ToList();
```

which, for SQL Server, translates to a single SQL query.  In EF Core:

```
  SELECT [t1].[ModelMessageId], [t1].[DateAdded], [t1].[Msg], [t1].[TaskId]
  FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT [m].[TaskId]
      FROM [ModelMessages] AS [m]
      WHERE [m].[DateAdded] >= DATEADD(day, CAST(-3.0E0 AS int), CONVERT(date, GETUTCDATE()))
  ) AS [t]
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT [t0].[ModelMessageId], [t0].[DateAdded], [t0].[Msg], [t0].[TaskId]
      FROM (
          SELECT [m0].[ModelMessageId], [m0].[DateAdded], [m0].[Msg], [m0].[TaskId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [m0].[TaskId] ORDER BY [m0].[DateAdded] DESC) AS [row]
          FROM [ModelMessages] AS [m0]
      ) AS [t0]
      WHERE [t0].[row] <= 6
  ) AS [t1] ON [t].[TaskId] = [t1].[TaskId]
```

EF6 generates a slightly different, but logically equivilent query:

```
SELECT
    [Project3].[ModelMessageId] AS [ModelMessageId],
    [Project3].[TaskId] AS [TaskId],
    [Project3].[Msg] AS [Msg],
    [Project3].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Limit1].[ModelMessageId] AS [ModelMessageId],
        [Limit1].[TaskId] AS [TaskId],
        [Limit1].[Msg] AS [Msg],
        [Limit1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded]
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT
            [Extent1].[TaskId] AS [TaskId]
            FROM [dbo].[ModelMessages] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[DateAdded] >= @p__linq__0 ) AS [Distinct1]
        CROSS APPLY  (SELECT TOP (6) [Project2].[ModelMessageId] AS [ModelMessageId], [Project2].[TaskId] AS [TaskId], [Project2].[Msg] AS [Msg], [Project2].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Extent2].[ModelMessageId] AS [ModelMessageId],
                [Extent2].[TaskId] AS [TaskId],
                [Extent2].[Msg] AS [Msg],
                [Extent2].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded]
                FROM [dbo].[ModelMessages] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Extent2].[TaskId] = [Distinct1].[TaskId]) OR (([Extent2].[TaskId] IS NULL) AND ([Distinct1].[TaskId] IS NULL))
            )  AS [Project2]
            ORDER BY [Project2].[DateAdded] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
    )  AS [Project3]
    ORDER BY [Project3].[TaskId] ASC, [Project3].[DateAdded] ASC
```

Comment: The results of this is incorrect. Ill have to look more into this. One I have the last 7 entries of each TaskId. I would like to order those is Ascending order by time . Your answer is missing something but I am not sure. Will need to look more into this.

Comment: It should be something like this `from m in db.Messages
                                    .Where(m => m.TaskId == t).OrderBy(order => order.DateAdded).TakeLast(6)` but TakeLast does not work for entity. Any idea how to extract the last 6 items ?

Comment: `OrderBy(order => order.DateAdded).TakeLast(6)` == `OrderByDescending(order => order.DateAdded).Take(6)`

Comment: David's answer will give you the last 6 messages, but as-is they will be in descending order. To get those last 6 but in ascending order: use `var results = q.OrderBy(x => x.DateAdded).ToList();` at the end. I would recommend the use of `Take` /w reverse order rather than `TakeLast` (.Net 5 / Core)  as I would suspect the later would need to iterate over the entire set. (?)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is very inefficient, because it is pulling back the whole list, and pushing it back to the server again. It is also effectively a self-join.

I think this is best done using window functions. Not sure if there is any way to do this in Entity Framework without executing raw SQL, but the SQL you need would be something like the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        FIRST_VALUE(DateAdded) OVER (PARTITION BY TaskId ORDER BY DateAdded DESC) AS Recent,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TaskId ORDER BY DateAdded DESC) AS rn
    FROM Messages
) m
WHERE Recent > @currentDate AND rn <= 6;
```

If anyone can translate this to EF, feel free to add it to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `GroupBy` extension method of `IQueryable<T>`:

```cs
private List<ModelMessage> Results()
{
    // your code
    
    //Get all messages grouped by TaskId.
    List<IGrouping<string, ModelMessage>> tasks = dbcontext.Messages.Where(x => x.DateAdded > currenteDate).GroupBy(x => x.TaskId).ToList();

    foreach (IGrouping<string, ModelMessage> task in tasks)
    {
        //Get the last 6 messages
        collection.AddRange(task.OrderBy(order => order.DateAdded).TakeLast(6));
    }

    return collection;
}
```

`GroupBy` return a [IGrouping<TKey,TElement>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-5.0) which you can iterate over to get each group of `TElement`.